# Problema comunicación entre PHP y AJAX. Paso de parámetro booleano erróneo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, pdo

Alguien sabe por qué esto me devuelve **false** en el Script de jQuery?
Envío el user y el pass desde el formulario, lo mando a PHP desde jQuery y recupero la información del login en **true o false** para validar la acción posteriormente

Cuando la ejecuto, esta clase me devuelve: ***{"arrayGlobalDatos":{"successA":true}}***

```
    header('content-type: application/json');
    $getusername = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'username');
    $getpassword = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'password');

        if($getusername && $getpassword) {
            $get_comer = ClaseUsuarios::consultaSinFormatoLogineo($getusername,$getpassword);
            $username    =$get_comer->getUsuario();
            $password    =$get_comer->getPassword();
            $count       =$get_comer->getCount();
                //la query me devuelve 1
                if($count == 1) {                
                    $arrayGlobalDatos= ["successA"=>true];                              
                } else {
                   $arrayGlobalDatos= ["successB"=>false];
                }        
        } else {
            $arrayGlobalDatos= ["successC"=>false];
        }

        $respuesta["arrayGlobalDatos"] = $arrayGlobalDatos;
        $myjoson = json_encode($respuesta);
        echo $myjoson;
```

cuando la llamo desde el JS así (previamente envio el user y el pass) me devuelve false en la función *validar()*

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#login_form").click(function () {
            var username = $("#lenamedelusuari").val();
            var password = $("#lepassdelusuari").val();
            authenticate(username, password);
        });
    });


    function authenticate(username, password) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "GET",
            url: ruta+"login.worker.php",
            data: 
            { 
                'username': username,
                'password': password
              },
            success: function () {
                validar();
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError);
                window.location.href = rutaC+"login.html";
            }
        })
    }

    function validar() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
             if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {       
                 var objetoTipoTienda = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                 var colA = objetoTipoTienda["arrayGlobalDatos"].successA;
                 var colB = objetoTipoTienda["arrayGlobalDatos"].successB;
                 var colC = objetoTipoTienda["arrayGlobalDatos"].successC;

                console.log(colA);
                console.log(colB);
                console.log(colC);

          } 
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", ruta+"login.worker.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

NOTA: no pongo la query porque como indico, la clase PHP me hace el read bien y me devuelve el resultado que luego parseo.

Comment: no sería más fácil hacer `success: function(data){console.log(data)}`?

Comment: Estás enviando credenciales de login por `GET`? Deberías enviarlas por `POST`. Como bien dice @Sr1871, hacé un `console.log()` de la respuesta del success a ver que está devolviendo.

Comment: @Sr1871 sí, pero eso no resolvería mi problema y ahora me sirve para diferenciar qué estoy obteniendo

Comment: @azeós  como ya menciono, obtengo "false"